# Replacing null in a list column pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like below and trying to replace the null using df.fillna(0) or df.fillna("nn"), both seem to have no impact on the dataframe. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

      `id    |     value
+-----------+------------+
          1 |   ["a","b","c"]
          6 |      null`

Comment: df.fillna(0) only has effects on numeric columns, df.fillna("nn") on string columns. that means the value column is neither a numeric nor a string type or null in the 2nd row is a literal string. can you show df.printSchema()

Comment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

Comment: df.fillna does not support complex datatype (`array`, `struct` etc ), you can use SQL expression: `df.withColumn('value', F.expr("coalesce(value, array('nn'))"))` or use API functions: coalesce + array + lit.  this will convert `null` to an array with one item `nn`.

Comment: if you want to fill in with an empty array, then just `coalesce(value, array())`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have assigned your new data frame to your old one? because it doesnt do it inplace.
you should do this:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.fillna("nn")
```

Comment: Yes, i'm assigning to a new dataframe. The issue here is fillna cannot handle complex datatypes.